# Debugging C/C++ in VSCode when using different directories

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to be able to debug my program when using different directories .

Let's take this example below :

[image]

Where main.c contains :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib/A.h"

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

A.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

void test();
```

A.c :

```
#include "A.h"

void test()
{
   printf("A\n");
   printf("B\n");
}
```

When I try to debug this program(Breakpoint in the main program), I get this error below :

```
The prelaunchtask C/C++ g++.exe build active file temrinated with exit code -1
```

However when if I remove A.c and write the whole function in the header file , **debugging will work correctly** :

A.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
   printf("A\n");
   printf("B\n");
}
```

I might have to change something in tasks.json or settings.json, but I don't know what should be modified so that I could debug a program with A.c - A.h - main.c .

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json :

```
   {

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried some solutions that I found but none of them worked that's why I wanted to post this question

Comment: you use multiple cpp files so use a Build tool like CMake, g++ terminates, read the error

Comment: Only building the active file is not a very useful feature, since pretty much any non-trivial program is spread out over multiple files.

Comment: In `tasks.json` the bug is `"${file}",` which means build using only the active file. Not all the files in multiple folders. The official documentation explains this: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) after you look at this and find `"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp"` note that this likely won't be recursive. You may need a separate entry for each folder. Or follow the first comment as CMake is a good solution.